# how to split a large csv file in unix command line

Tags: unix, awk, printf

I am just splitting a  very large csv file in to parts. When ever i run the following command. the doesn't completely split rather returns me the following error. how can i avoid the split the whole file.

```
       awk -F, '{print > $2}' test1.csv 

       awk: YY1 makes too many open files
       input record number 31608, file test1.csv
       source line number 1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just `close` the files after writing:

```
awk -F, '{print > $2; close($2)}' test1.csv
```

Comment: ```awk -F, '{print >> $2; close($2)}' test1.csv``` unless all you are after is one line

Answer (score 0):

You must have a lot of lines.  Are you sure that the second row repeats enough to put those records into an individual file?  Anyway, awk is holding the files open until the end.  You'll need a process that can close the file handles when not in use.

Perl to the rescue.  Again.

```
#!perl    
while( <> ) {
    @content = split /,/, $_;
    open ( OUT, ">> $content[1]") or die "whoops: $!";
    print OUT $_;
    close OUT;
}
```

usage: `script.pl your_monster_file.csv`

outputs the entire line into a file named the same as the value of the second CSV column in the current directory, assuming no quoted fields etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, I am using the second column in the file. I ll try your perl script

Comment: Just noticed that I missed the ">>" on the open command.  Would only get the last line without that.

Comment: A "lot" of files? I just hit this error while processing a 10GB file containing 10 million records and trying to split it into 1000 files of 10,000 records each! awk gave up when it got to 16 open files :-)